# How to convert an Arduino sketch into a C file in Code::blocks?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, embedded-resource

How to convert an Arduino sketch into a C file in Code::blocks?

I don't know why this industry (Embedded Systems) is so poor in documentation. Everybody told me that in this field there are a lot of documentation to read... fine... I know for datasheets, but for some little code conversion (Arduino sketch to C in Code::blocks) I can't find even 1 example to see how it works...

Comment: Arduino is more like C++. You'll have a lot of work converting to C.

Comment: And there is a chance to work with headers and C files just to have 2/3 files from 1 Arduino sketch? And with C++, there is a hope? Can't find a solution... maybe I don't know how to dig deeper.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? It depends on what the code does. If it is mostly computation that will be easier to convert than a sketch which manipulates the hardware. There is a lot of functionality in the Arduino libraries, one reason why it is a popular choice. Standard C is platform-agnostic. 2 or 3 files in one language might be a dozen in another. When I first wrote a java program to broadcast a UDP datagram I was amazed that the program was little more than one function.

Comment: Code::Blocks can C++. but it is an IDE while Arduino is a platform so what do you want to do? do you want to develop for Arduino hardware in Code::Blocks IDE?

Comment: Note that Sketch is C++ in a framework, not C.  Also the whole Arduino framework is not just the sketch - it is the libraries, hardware platforms, compilation tools, build system  and device programming.  Code::Blocks is just an IDE, once you've "converted" this code, what is it going to run on?  How are you going to build it and for what? Have you set Code::Blocks up to use Arduino?  Is that even possible?

Comment: Ok, I see that is somehow crazy, I'll try next days to see what to do or to know what to do, maybe I'm not so fresh in thinking, but I saw (not on Internet but live... at work...) an example of Arduino sketch converted in C for Code:blocks with some libraries and header files, it was surprising for me and now I want to see that again, that's why I'm trying to do that...

Comment: Yes, it is possible to set Code::Blocks for Arduino, you need Atmel Studio... maybe too much... I don't know.

Comment: @ajoh : Then it is no longer truly "Arduino", rather just an AVR toolchain and development board.  It is the framework and ecosystem that makes it Arduino - if you choose to not use it, then any AVR development information and tool chain is relevant.   Code::Blocks is an interesting project but not specifically targeted at embedded systems - hence the lack of documentation from the "industry".  You have not chosen the simplest path perhaps.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Clifford, then I'll try something else (but first I need a break :D)

Comment: Try AVRFReaks:  https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avr-gcc-code-blocks-codeblocks?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=38735

Comment: I wonder, what if you saw was based on this (even though it was updated a very while ago.. )  http://arduinodev.com/codeblocks/

Comment: @kesselhaus, no, not this, I saw Code::Blocks and the program was build/run and what was in Console was at Hardware (Arduino leds/buttons)

Comment: Arduino is a _hobbyist_ platform, not an industry platform. Documentation is intentionally brief, because student users are expected to have very little knowledge.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, this problem seems to be Grandpa and Arduino is grandchild; the problem is more complicated, I need a framework... made of Arduino, Atmel Studio and Code::Blocks, all of them united in Code::Blocks, yeah... too much for me, but I saw that and I was impressed.

Comment: @ajroh Why would you want to use Codeblocks? It's a generic IDE, it doesn't have a clue about microcontroller specifics, like Atmel Studio will have. Serial monitors are stone age technology, use an in-circuit debugger. Atmel have very cheap ones of their own brand. But then of course Arduino itself is stone age stuff too... I wouldn't use an AVR in the year 2019 even if they paid me to use it.

Comment: :)), thank you; I'm young enough to prefer old stone technology (learn from elder, play with younger...)

Answer (score 4):

Although this might be more of a comment I'd like to use an answer hoping that my "comment" answers your question.

> don't know why this industry (Embedded Systems) is so poor in
>   documentation.

That is not true. Documentation of hard and software for embedded systems is very well documeneted. The manuals for Atmel AVR MCUs that power most of the Arduino models is excellent.

Converting Arduino sketches to Code::Blocks is a very special project. It is not surprising that you won't find a complete working tutorial on it.
Rather learn how to use Code::Blocks, how Arduino works and how to program AVRs from scratch. You'll find a ton of tutorials/resources on that. Then you combine that knowledge to your project. (that's a good approach to pretty much any problem you'll face in life. break it down)

There is also a vibrant and very kind community. All you need to do is show that you actually did some own work and you'll be overwhelmed with support.

Arduino is aimed at people with zero to little programming experience. Their takes away most hard work and thinking. You don't have to read 400 page manuals and manipulate registers on bitlevel to get a LED to blink or a motor to turn. You just call a few functions and that's it.
It uses some simplified C++ dialect and a lot of libraries and convenience stuff behind the curtain to allow that.

You don't have to worry about programmers, flashing firmware, setting up project files, writing make files and whatnot.

If you want to do the same without the Arduino IDE I highly recommend that you get yourself a book on AVR programming in C++ and if you don't know C++ to at least a medium level another one on C++. Somehow frankensteining Arduino sketches into a normal IDE doesn't appear to promissing in the long run.
You can make more out of your time.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your kind answer, is very well structured (even if is not what I'm searching for, it is useful)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert a arduino sketch into codeblocks. The problem is that the arduino ide does all sorts of things behind our backs which makes it easier for a novice to begin programming a microcontroller.

The easiest way would be to start a *new* avr project in codeblocks and follow a tutorial on how to program a generic avr microcontroller using codeblocks. This might involve getting a ISP programmer or figuring out how to program using the arduino bootloader over serial.

You can start converting your arduino project to codeblocks after you've wholly understood the basic programming method using codeblocks. This is going to involve you writing your own definitions for `digital_write` and `pinMode`.

Your assertions about poor documentation is plain wrong. AVR is really well documented. You should try to read their documentation instead of Arduino's since that is targeted at novices or hobbyist who just want it to work. They hide much of the more fine tuned information.

Comment: Ok, thank you, the problem is more complicated than I presented (I need Arduino-Serial Monitor; Atmel Studio and Code::Blocks), is more like a framework (that guy who did that is a genius) and then it will work... with several functions/headers/C files (now I realized that it was a specific project, it was a framework, 2 projects: 1 for C, 1 for Arduino), nevermind, this topic has been disabled since now.

Comment: First there is no need for arduino-serial monitor, atmel studio and codeblocks together at the same time. C++ can use C frameworks and disabling a question doesn't work like that. Just delete your question if it is malformed, irrelevant or unanswerable.

Comment: is not irrelevant :)), is very relevant, for a new era (maybe), right now is useful for others to know that you can create your own framework in Code::Blocks who can run from/with Arduino (some board...), and you can work simultaneously in 2 projects, 1 for Code::Blocks and 1 for Arduino (1 run/build for Windows, 1 run/build for Arduino - Serial Monitor). Yeah, I saw before that it still fascinating me that... I can't delete this question, after few months I'll come back to this problem and why not to build my own framework...

Comment: So your question just was: can I create a library that works in Arduino, atmel studio and codeblocks? Then the answer is yes, and the question is out of scope for SO.

Comment: :)), not really, because that was yesterday, now I offered a new perspective :D, and I put '*DISABLED' before the question. The scope was to know how it is possible to do that, now I have an idea, perhaps tomorrow I will do by myself... Sorry for your inconvenience.